# How to make a Tubular 3D Trail

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Objective:** I'm trying to make the trail of a sphere. I want it to be tubular, like this:

[image]

I was trying to achieve it with **LineRenderer** and **TrailRenderer** component, but both components work with lines, so the generated trails are bidimensional, no tridimensional, looking like this:

[image]

My other approach was to create a cylinder shape, add the transparent material and try to put one cylinder after another on the points of the trajectory, but the result is not the desired as it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You could generate the [mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) procedurally.

Comment: Id have said maybe particles that start spread and get narrower

Comment: the shown picture most likely has a bidimensional renderer aswell, but adds lightning to the trail. if you want it for something similiar to the first picture i think 3d would be a wast of resources. have you looked at https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/387pwc/rendering_3d_trails/ ?

Comment: Thanks to all, I'll take a look to the link, but my problem is not the performance, I need the EXACT look as the image, beside the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found that UnifyCommunity has the answer with his **TubeRenderer** component: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=TubeRenderer&oldid=17443

The only thing to know is that the script requires to add a mesh clearing after creating the `new Mesh();`

To achieve it type: `mesh.Clear();` before assign vertices etc